# Need to set number formatter for jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to set number formatter to colModel to which I am passing a value in the form of an object like Need to set the number formatter for up to 2 decimal points. I have added the formatter referring the documentation, but not able to set on the colmodel attribute

```
colModel: $scope.colModelValue
```

The sample code is like:

```
function drawGrid() {
                $("#grid").jqGrid("GridUnload");
                var grid = $("#grid"),lastSel;
                jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
                    formatter : {
                    number : {decimalSeparator:".", thousandsSeparator: " ", decimalPlaces: 2, defaultValue: '0.00'}},
                    sortable: true,
                    datatype: "local",
                    data: $scope.jqGridData,
                    colNames: $scope.jqgridColHeader, 
                    colModel: $scope.colModelValue,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    caption: "Peer Analysis",
                    rowNum:10,
                    rowList:[10,20,30],
                    recordpos: 'left',
                    footerrow : true,
                    userDataOnFooter : true,
                    restoreAfterSelect: false,
                    saveAfterSelect: true,
                    altRows : true,
                    multiselect: true,
                    cellEdit:   true,
                    autowidth:true,
                    treeGrid: true,
                    grouping: true,
                    shrinkToFit: true,
                    pager: '#pager',
                    gridview: true,
                    'cellEdit': true,
                    'cellsubmit' : 'clientArray',
                    editurl: 'clientArray',
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <=4.7

Comment: i am using jqGrid 4.6 version

Answer (score 1):

You read  in documentation the setting in the language part. In order to set the formatter options you should  do this in the colModel using the formatoptions property and not in grid options like you do. In your case you should modify the colModel field like this:

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
...
   colModel : [
   ...
      {name:'myname', ... formatter:'number', formatoptions:{decimalSeparator: ".", thousandsSeparator: " ", decimalPlaces: 2, defaultValue: '0.00'} } ,
   ...
   ],
...
});
```

Note that the property formatter:'number' should be in lower case